# What exactly does x[row].length do?

Tags: java, arrays

```
public class MultiDimen {
    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        int firstArray[][] = { { 8, 9, 19, 11 }, { 12, 13, 14, 15 }, };
        int secondArray[][] = { { 30, 31, 32, 33 }, { 43 }, { 4, 5, 6, }, };
        System.out.println("This is the first Array");
        display(firstArray);
        System.out.println("This is the second Array");
        display(secondArray);

    }

    public static void display(int x[][]) {
        for (int row = 0; row < x.length; row++) {

            System.out.println("ROW:" + x[row].length + "[row].length");

            for (int column = 0; column < x[row].length; column++) {

                System.out.print(x[row][column] + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

I understand what is going on here, however, one thing that is unclear is what x[row].length does? 
I understand that x.length gets the length of the array of colomns x that was passed in. But row is not an array it was declared as an int so why would we do this?

Comment: as it is a two dimensional array it reports the array length of x[row]

Comment: `length` is the built-in property of an array in Java. It is used to determine the size of any array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example, using your own code, will best explain what `x[row].length` is doing:

```
int secondArray[][]={
        {30,31,32,33},
        {43},
        {4,5,6,},
};

for (int row=0; row < secondArray.length; ++row) {
    System.out.println("Row " + (row+1) + " has " + secondArray[row].length + " elements.");
}
```

`row[i].length` yields the number of elements in the 1D `int[]` array contained at the ith position of your 2D `int[][]` array.

**Output:**

```
Row 1 has 4 elements.
Row 2 has 1 elements.
Row 3 has 3 elements.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int numOfRows = matrix.length;
int numOfCols = matrix[0].length;
```